# plotting separate curves on data in R

Tags: r, regression, curve-fitting, data-fitting, non-linear-regression

I have a plot where the for every x values there are 2 Y values. The data is also non-linear. The plot looks like this:

[image]

Now my question is I want to fit to regression curves separately to two of those curves (upper and lower). I know this is not a clear question as there is not unique identification scheme that I have in hand but I know the response system can behave in two different ways for a same input (or almost same input) at random.

[The data file can be found here the headers used here 'sigma' and 'mabs_b'](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jip27xnnv34fixm/SIS_TFFJ_all_sorted_R.list?dl=0)

Summary of full dataset:

```
 summary(data)
#       id            sigma             L_gal               M_gal                flux         
# Min.   :    1   Min.   :  6.214   Min.   :1.481e+06   Min.   :1.541e+08   Min.   :    10.4  
# 1st Qu.: 5118   1st Qu.: 28.438   1st Qu.:1.814e+08   1st Qu.:1.290e+10   1st Qu.:   196.7  
# Median :10236   Median : 41.542   Median :6.725e+08   Median :3.684e+10   Median :   388.0  
# Mean   :10236   Mean   : 56.599   Mean   :3.151e+09   Mean   :3.663e+11   Mean   :  2551.5  
# 3rd Qu.:15354   3rd Qu.: 65.445   3rd Qu.:2.467e+09   3rd Qu.:1.410e+11   3rd Qu.:  1227.3  
# Max.   :20471   Max.   :391.988   Max.   :3.810e+11   Max.   :2.960e+13   Max.   :733660.0  
#    fluxmax             mabs_b            flag            cstar          
# Min.   :   1.191   Min.   :-24.25   Min.   : 0.000   Min.   :0.0001578  
# 1st Qu.:   5.801   1st Qu.:-18.77   1st Qu.: 0.000   1st Qu.:3.0000000  
# Median :  10.111   Median :-17.36   Median : 0.000   Median :3.0000000  
# Mean   :  39.649   Mean   :-17.33   Mean   : 1.217   Mean   :2.5267219  
# 3rd Qu.:  26.313   3rd Qu.:-15.94   3rd Qu.: 3.000   3rd Qu.:3.0000000  
# Max.   :6600.280   Max.   :-10.72   Max.   :51.000   Max.   :3.0000000
```

Output of `head(data,20)`:

```
subset_data = structure(list(id = 1:20, sigma = c(391.988, 379.985, 363.682, 
358.969, 362.63, 344.544, 344.544, 331.482, 332.665, 302.539, 
306.977, 287.416, 205.793, 303.279, 297.047, 273.719, 214.59, 
268.891, 291.834, 191.926), L_gal = c(3.81e+11, 3.35e+11, 2.98e+11, 
2.98e+11, 2.93e+11, 2.19e+11, 2.19e+11, 1.84e+11, 1.68e+11, 1.43e+11, 
1.42e+11, 1.12e+11, 1.05e+11, 1.03e+11, 1.02e+11, 9.27e+10, 92017300000, 
91078100000, 85536700000, 83359400000), M_gal = c(2.96e+13, 2.68e+13, 
2.23e+13, 2.05e+13, 2.21e+13, 1.99e+13, 1.99e+13, 1.78e+13, 1.94e+13, 
1.21e+13, 1.34e+13, 1.06e+13, 4.01e+12, 1.56e+13, 1.38e+13, 8.95e+12, 
5.16e+12, 8.12e+12, 1.4e+13, 3.28e+12), flux = c(156286, 129987, 
67801.2, 50110.3, 73118.6, 80827.2, 80827.2, 68568, 142348, 21194.6, 
31081.9, 17414.4, 12121.3, 167441, 81709.3, 13920.7, 51775.8, 
8185.93, 159998, 17393.7), fluxmax = c(6508.29, 4956.37, 2381.87, 
2200.22, 2986.29, 2396.81, 2396.81, 2278.94, 4875.65, 854.856, 
1264.36, 750.337, 19.7162, 6082.21, 724.639, 204.966, 281.601, 
214.372, 6304.41, 182.002), mabs_b = c(-24.2475, -24.1079, -23.9807, 
-23.9799, -23.9618, -23.6449, -23.6449, -23.4586, -23.3587, -23.1847, 
-23.1745, -22.9178, -22.8463, -22.826, -22.8183, -22.7122, -22.7042, 
-22.693, -22.6249, -22.5969), flag = c(35L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 35L, 2L, 3L, 35L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L), cstar = c(0.989659, 
0.989581, 0.988048, 0.993796, 0.986398, 0.990529, 0.990529, 0.997505, 
0.995231, 0.990121, 0.986176, 0.984495, 0.0007165, 0.987469, 
0.0287568, 0.379966, 0.028632, 0.898742, 0.999391, 0.0286844)), .Names = c("id", 
"sigma", "L_gal", "M_gal", "flux", "fluxmax", "mabs_b", "flag", 
"cstar"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: If you have a variable identifying upper and lower points, then you can 1. use it as an indicator in your estimator; or 2. run separate estimations on each group.

Comment: If you need help choosing an appropriate statistical method for your data, you should be asking over at [stats.se]. Otherwise make it clear exactly what you would like R to do for you. How should the computer put points into groups. Unless you can answer that, your question doesn't belong on this site. What is the statistical model you want to use?

Comment: @MrFlick What if the question was like "how to apply regression in R for the given data, with the data divided into two separate  bins ?"

Comment: "Apply regression" isn't very specific. What model are you trying to run? If your data can be separated into groups, then your sample input data should have such an indicator.

Comment: The data can't be divided into groups based on an indicator I have mentioned that. The visual description at present is the only way to distinguish atleast for me. I attempted a quadratic  least square fit

Comment: You said that every x has 2 y values.  Does the higher y always fall in the upperr curve and vice versa? If so, it is trivial to separate the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two clusters of points with a gap in between. The data does not contain an indicator. I assume you want to define, a priori, that points lying above the gap should be in one group and points lying below the gap should be in another group.

In that case, I'm afraid there is no getting around this without creating an indicator variable for the two groups yourself.

Luckily, this can be done using the locator() function. In this case, the function works because there's a clear gap between the two groups. It remains to use locator() to trace a line through the gap and check which sigma values lie above and below that traced line.

Once you have this indicator, you can use any fitting method you like...but that's a matter for a different post (perhaps on Cross Validated).

```
library('ggplot2')

d<-read.csv("SIS_TFFJ_all_sorted_R.csv")

uniq_sigma<-unique(d$sigma)

gap<-locator()
```

Here are the contents of gap from my trace:

```
> gap
$x
 [1] -24.66446 -24.45990 -24.15305 -23.74391 -23.48820 -22.82336 -22.46536 -22.12442 -21.74938 -21.40843 -21.06749 -20.70950 -20.52198 -19.89123 -20.07875 -19.31162 -18.66382 -18.25469 -17.82851
[20] -17.07842 -16.39653 -15.64645 -15.08389 -14.24858 -13.44735 -12.40747 -11.19711

$y
 [1] 346.67767 331.34710 315.20967 294.23100 277.28669 249.85305 229.68126 213.54382 194.17890 173.20024 159.48342 145.76660 136.08413 120.75357 123.98106 107.84362  92.51306  87.67183  79.60311
[20]  67.50003  58.62444  49.74885  44.10075  38.45265  30.38393  23.92896  17.47398
```

Now that I have an estimate of the line dividing the two groups, I can simply check which points are above and below the line.

```
d$x_pos<-cut(d$mabs_b, gap$x)
names(gap$y)<-unique(d$x_pos)
d$y_pos<-gap$y[d$x_pos]

d$cohort<-ifelse(d$sigma>d$y_pos,'upper','lower')
```

Finally, the plotting with model fitting using geom_smooth(). Again, what model you want to fit is a whole different question...one that is more suited for Cross Validated.

```
ggplot(data=d, aes(x=mabs_b, y=sigma, col=cohort, group=cohort))+geom_point()+geom_smooth(col='black')
```

[image]